# Is it a good idea to init ajax functions only while 'DOING_AJAX'

Tags: ajax

I wonder if it is a good solution to add (a lot) ajax [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) only if `DOING_AJAX`is defined.

Normally my setup is something like this:

```
add_action('init', 'my_ajax_init');

function my_ajax_init(){
    add_action('wp_ajax_mymail_method_1', 'my_ajax_method_1');
    add_action('wp_ajax_mymail_method_2', 'my_ajax_method_2');
    add_action('wp_ajax_mymail_method_3', 'my_ajax_method_3');
    add_action('wp_ajax_mymail_method_4', 'my_ajax_method_4');
    ....
}
```

I could prevent this actions on a "normal" page view with this:

```
if(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX){
  add_action('init', 'my_ajax_init');  
}
```

Would this help in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to know is to test yourself...but you will most likely find that the performance difference is negligible. Adding those actions don't mean that the "my_ajax_method_" will be evaluated. It is just setting up a reference...and the reference is only executed if the AJAX call comes in.

Comment: ok, so can I stop putting any effort to reduce the use of `add_action` for performance reasons?

Comment: In my opinion, yes